# How to handle SOAP FAULT in response using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, soap, xslt-1.0, mule

I have a Proxy webservice in Mule where I am using XSLT transformation response to modify the response ... It works fine and response is somewhat like :-

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <retrieveDataResponse xmlns="http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1">
         <Response>The Data retrieved from the Database</Response>
         <Id>3</Id>
         <Name>anir</Name>
         <Age>44</Age>
         <Designation>SE</Designation>
      </retrieveDataResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Now the issue is when any SOAP fault occurs say **UNMARSHAL_ERROR**, The response do not shows the SOAP fault ... it is somewhat like :-

```
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <retrieveDataResponse xmlns="http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1">
         <Response/>
      </retrieveDataResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But it should show the **SOAP Fault** ... If I remove XSLT from response it works fine and shows the response with **SOAP Fault** .. but if I place XSLT again it's not showing fault in response .. How can I modify my XSLT so that it handles the SOAP fault ..... My XSLT is as follows :-

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:md1="http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1"
    exclude-result-prefixes="md1">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <soap:Envelope>
            <soap:Body>
                <retrieveDataResponse xmlns="http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1">
                    <Response>
                        <xsl:value-of
                            select="soap:Envelope/soap:Body/md1:retrieveDataResponse/md1:Response" />
                    </Response>
                    <xsl:if
                        test="soap:Envelope/soap:Body/md1:retrieveDataResponse/md1:Response='The Data retrieved from the Database'">
                        <Id>
                            <xsl:value-of
                                select="soap:Envelope/soap:Body/md1:retrieveDataResponse/md1:Id" />
                        </Id>
                        <Name>
                            <xsl:value-of
                                select="soap:Envelope/soap:Body/md1:retrieveDataResponse/md1:Name" />
                        </Name>
                        <Age>
                            <xsl:value-of
                                select="soap:Envelope/soap:Body/md1:retrieveDataResponse/md1:Age" />
                        </Age>
                        <Designation>
                            <xsl:value-of
                                select="soap:Envelope/soap:Body/md1:retrieveDataResponse/md1:Designation" />
                        </Designation>
                    </xsl:if>
                </retrieveDataResponse>
            </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please Help ... How to modify my XSLT to catch SOAP Fault

Comment: Your curretn XSLT is just reproducing the RetrieveDataResponse XMl with SOAP Envelope that it receives as response. Why are you using XSLT for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would design the XSLT more modular and then take it step by step:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:md1="http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1"
    xmlns="http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1"
    exclude-result-prefixes="md1">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    <xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="soap:Envelope">
        <soap:Envelope>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </soap:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="soap:Body">
          <soap:Body>
             <xsl:apply-templates />
          </soap:Body>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="retrieveDataResponse">
        <retrieveDataResponse>
                    <Response>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Response" />
                    </Response>
                    <xsl:if test="Response='The Data retrieved from the Database'">
                        <Id>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Id" />
                        </Id>
                        <Name>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Name" />
                        </Name>
                        <Age>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Age" />
                        </Age>
                        <Designation>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Designation" />
                        </Designation>
                    </xsl:if>
                </retrieveDataResponse>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

A little verbose, but you get the idea. It doesn't do a lot of transformation. Typically you would strip off the envelope so processing becomes easier. if you want to suppress a specific element, you always can use `<xsl:template match="prefix:element" />` this would suppress all output of such an element. [Recommended reading](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/XSLT-2-0-and-XPath-2-0-Programmer-s-Reference-4th-Edition.productCd-0470192747.html).

Let us know how it goes!

Comment: It's working perfect ... I am getting a minor issue ... I want if Response value is "The Data retrieved from the Database", then only attributes like Id, Age, Name and Designation will display ... But even if the value of Response is not that ... the attributes like Age and Id are displayed with value 0 ... It may me some fault in my wsdl and the same value was coming on actual host webservice response .. Thats the reason I choose XSLT for this Proxy to prevent the values of Id and Age when response value is not that .. Here also in your modified xslt I need to stop displaying Age,Id value ..

Comment: Anyways .. Thanks for the response

Comment: You can blend them out using the method I mentioned (empty template) or add select statements to to the apply-templates. Feel free to accept the answer

Comment: Since you are processing anyway, strip the envelope away, so you actually only process further what you need. Keeps the code base clean